# conda install cannot find colmap package

Tags: python, windows-10, conda

I am trying to install [colmap](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/colmap) with conda on Windows 10.
unfortunately it says it cannot find the package despite me having already added the conda-forge channel.
Below is the output:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\pietro> conda install -c conda-forge colmap
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - colmap

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I tried to reappend condaforge, and to set my offline status to false, but still no luck.

Thanks for any help!
Cheers
pietro

Answer (score 0):

### Update

This should just work now - the Conda Forge feedstock now builds for Windows as well.

### Original response

[The Conda Forge `colmap` feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/colmap-feedstock) currently does not build for the **win-64** platform. There is [a GitHub Issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/colmap-feedstock/issues/3) requesting/tracking such support, and even [a Pull Request](https://github.com/conda-forge/colmap-feedstock/pull/4) that tested adding Windows builds. Please comment on those threads to let the maintainer know that users are interested in seeing that build variant supported.